# Ternary operators gives compilation errors

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I'm trying to print the result based on the input of arithmetic operator

```
double n1= 45;
double n2= 9;

double result = (mathOperator == '/') ? n1/n2 : 
                (mathOperator == '+') ? n1+n2 : 
                (mathOperator == '-') ? n1-n2 : 
                (mathOperator == '*') ? n1*n2;

System.out.println(result);
```

but I'm getting an error message at the end of the ternary line with semicolon there

can anyone please help me understand, where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Arun Sudhakaran, Thank You!

Comment: please accept the answer if my solution has fixed your issue.

Comment: *ternary* comes from THREE because that operator needs three operands - `(mathOperator == '*') ? n1*n2` only has TWO -- I would recommended using a `switch` expression (or statement) in this case; also recommended to have some error handling (message?) in case the `mathOperator` is none of the valid options

Comment: This is a perfect case for a switch expression: `double result = switch(mathOperator) { case '/' -> n1/n2; case '+' -> n1+n2; case '-' -> n1-n2; case '*' -> n1*n2; default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid operator: " + mathOperator); };`

Comment: Ohhhh ok got it

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran, how do I accept your answer?... sorry for delayed reply, seeing your message just now

Comment: You can accept it by clicking the tick mark below the vote button. https://stackoverflow.com/tour#:~:text=The%20person%20who%20asked%20can%20mark%20one%20answer%20as%20%22accepted%22.

Answer (score 2):

How the **Ternary operators** work

```
(condition) ? (consider this value/expression when the condition is true) : 
              (consider this value/expression when the condition is false);
```

Now, in your code, all the other operators satisfy the above condition, but for multiplication the `else` part is missing.

So you can end your condition like this

```
mathOperator =='*'? n1*n2 : 0;
```

A better way would be

```
mathOperator =='*'? n1*n2 : Double.NaN;
```

Comment: Nit: it's not _do_ when the condition is true/false, it's _value_ when the condition is true/false. This is important, because you can only put expressions there, not statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition false is missing

```
double result = (mathOperator == '/') ? n1/n2 : 
                (mathOperator == '+') ? n1+n2 : 
                (mathOperator == '-') ? n1-n2 : 
                (mathOperator == '*') ? n1*n2 : 0;
```

Comment: got it, Thank You @Aloysius Tri Sulistyo Putranto

Comment: welcome sir @ImMe ....